# Using Python to download an Excel file from OneDrive results in corrupt file

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint, onedrive

I am trying to download an excel file from a OneDrive location.  My code works okay to get the file, but the file is corrupt (I get an error message):

```
import urllib2

data = urllib2.urlopen("enter url here")
with open('C:\\Video.xlsx', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(data.read())
output.close()
print "done"
```

I use the guest access to the excel file so that I don't have to work with authentication.  The resulting file seems to be 15KB, the original is 22KB.

Comment: if you enter the same url in your browser, do you get a download or does it show a Excel web interface? In case of the latter, that's basically what you've written to file as well. You should make sure that the url is pointing directly at the binary file. Also, make sure that you don't need to authenticate first. In short, look at the contents of `data`, that might clear up a thing or two.

Comment: If you open the file you downloaded in a text editor do you see a HTML page with JavaScript?

Comment: @Kristof, I get the Excel interface.  I'm not sure how to get a link to the binary file..OneDrive is a little baffling when it comes to storing this stuff. I basically get a link like (this isn't a real one): https://my.sharepoint.com/personal/myname/layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?guestaccesstoken=abunchofcharacters=view

Comment: @Dan-Dev, good idea, yes it is the html page...so does anyone know how to get the actual binary or excel content?

Comment: I'd explore Kristof's answer first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just download the Excel file directly from OneDrive using a URL. Even when you would share the file without any authorization, you'll probably still get a link to an intermediate HTML page, rather than the Excel binary itself.

To download items from your OneDrive, you'll first need to authenticate and then pass the location of the file you're after. You'll probably want to use the OneDrive REST API. The details on how to do that are documented on the [OneDrive's SDK for Python](https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-python) GitHub page with some examples to get you started.

Comment: Apparently onedrivesdk is now deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

I got it. The url has the format below:

'https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=.....app=Excel'

So, all that I had to do was change "view" to "download" at that url, and used the code below:

```
import urllib.request

url = 'https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=.....app=Excel'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "test.xlsx")
```

Comment: This is a good solution-need to replace "view" with "download" in the above example. The edit queue is full.