# Using Python3 Sharepy to download an excel file from a shared 0365 Commercial sharepoint results in corrupt file

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint-online

Similar to a previous question that wasn't fully answered, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531278/using-python-to-download-an-excel-file-from-onedrive-results-in-corrupt-file), I am attempting to use Python3 and Sharepy to download an Excel file, manipulate it with pandas, and reupload it back to sharepoint.

The issue may be, I don't know where the true excel file is stored, I only have a reference link that can be shared to other people with access.  Downloading that link is an html to Excel Online and not the Excel file I was intending.  Any tips?

```
import sharepy
from sharepy import connect
from sharepy import SharePointSession

server='https://mycompany365.sharepoint.com'
user='first.m.last@mycompany.com'
password='1234Password1234'

# Copy/Paste file link from sharepoint below. #<--- partially works
site = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/Sales/Shared%20Documents/General/My_File.xlsx?d=wb182f80code74bd586b225codebeb1c&csf=1&e=CodeeT"

s = sharepy.connect(server,user,password)

#  Download file to same folder as python script, save as My_File.xlsx.
r = s.getfile(site,\
 filename = 'My_File.xlsx')

print("Script Complete")
```

My site = results in an html pointed at the correct online file but not the true Excel file.  How do I find where the true file is?

Answer (score 1):

After some brute force, I found that deleting the random code at the end of the "share link" opens the original file:

```
# Copy/Paste file link from sharepoint below. Before...
site = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/Sales/Shared%20Documents/General/My_File.xlsx?d=wb182f80code74bd586b225codebeb1c&csf=1&e=CodeeT"

# Copy/Paste file link from sharepoint below. After.
site = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/Sales/Shared%20Documents/General/My_File.xlsx"
```

Comment: This gives you a request response object 200 if successful. From there, How did you read the file as a dataframe?

Comment: After the Excel file is saved to my local folder, its just a matter of reading the Excel file into Pandas.  df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=0, index_col=None)

Comment: Yeah … it is what I do right now but it is not ideal … Would you know if there is an alternative where we would read the file directly instead of downloading it? Thanks!

Comment: @RenauV you should be able to do `r = s.get(url)`, which will give the file data as `r.content` https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer Arthur. It helped me resolving my issue of corrupted files. I was using this URL and was getting corrupted files after downloading.

```
url = 'https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/MyProject/Retainer%20Query/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FSnowfig%2FRetainer%20Query%2Fimage001.png'
```

I changed the url to this

```
url = 'https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/MyProject/Retainer%20Query/image001.png'
```

And now I can open these files.